# How to create daynamic tree panel in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, treepanel, extjs6

I want to have a **dynamic** **tree panel** in my project. I use from [**sencha docs**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/components/trees.html) example For this component.

But, I have a error when run my project:

**Ext.data.schema.Schema.lookupEntity(): No such Entity "Category".**

MyProject/Model/Category.js:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.model.Category',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});
```

MyProject/classic/src/view/category/Cateogry.js:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.view.category.Category', function(){

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Category',
    root: {
        name: 'Product'
    }
});

var items = [{
    items:[{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Name'
    },{
        xtype: 'treepanel',
        reference: 'treepanel',
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        frame: true,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Add',
        listeners: {
            click: 'onClick'
        }
    }]
}];

return{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.rtl.*'
    ],

    controller: 'categorycontroller',

    alias: 'widget.category',

    layout: 'vbox',

    items: items
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your model as required:

```
...
requires: [
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.rtl.*',
    'ProjectName.model.Category'
],
...
```